# Searching for posts in two categories

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been modifying Telescope to search for posts with two categories.

To do this I passed an object with the categories through my `PostsListController` in `router.js` and modified `parameters.js` by adding the following:

```
if (terms.categories) {
    _.extend(parameters.find, {$and: [{'categories.slug': terms.categories[0]}, 
    {'categories.slug': terms.categories[1]}]});
}
```

This seems like an ugly way to do this. What is the more "meteor-y" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a mongodb question I think.  Their [operator reference docs are here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/).

Besides $and mongo provides $all which is a shorter and slightly more clear.

```
_.extend(parameters.find, {'categories.slug': { $all: terms.categories }});
```